# error 0x80004005 when connecting to excel sheet

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am coding a classic asp routine for splitting and displaying data from a 2000 msExcel .XLS spreadsheet, connecting with this string:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
Conn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; IMEX=1; HDR=YES; "&_
"Excel 8.0; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath(OpenFile) & "; "
```

And after starting IIS7 localhost on my Dell Alien w/ Win7 professional the page updates immediately for the first half hour or so, but then starts to hang for a minute on every page refresh, giving me the 0X80004005 error pointing to the mappath line in the code. After the delay it refreshes once, but if I try to refresh again within the next minute, it hangs again

After restarting the machine I have another half hour of smooth testing until the problem arises again.

Does anyone have an idea of whats going on?

Comment: Are you closing and disposing of your connections properly? Sounds like a memory leak.

Comment: I believe so. I loop through the records: do while not XLSrec.EOF *** XLSrec.movenext loop and end the page with XlsRec.close()
set Xlsrec = nothing

Comment: Are you also closing and disposing Conn?

Comment: Ahh - never thought of it. Thanks for waking me up :) going to close Conn and see if that resolves the problem.